# how to insert javascript variable into json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

here is the function

```
function createData(_id){
var _temp = '20C';
var _battery = '60%';
var _data = { _id:{temp:_temp,battery:_battery} };
console.log(_data);
}
createData('Thermometer1');
```

Result :

```
[
_id:{temp:'20C',
     battery:'60%'
    }
]
```

Expected Result:

```
[
Thermometer1:{temp:'20C',
     battery:'60%'
    }
]
```

ignore the text below :v

it looks like your post is mostly code; please add more detail,

i don't know what to write so here is a guitar tab

0 - 3 - 5

0 - 3 - 6 - 5

0 - 3 - 5 - 3 - 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brackets around _id:

```
function createData(_id){
  var _temp = '20C';
  var _battery = '60%';
  var _data = { [_id]:{temp:_temp,battery:_battery} };
  console.log(_data);
}
createData('Thermometer1');
```

Edit: 
You can use a string to define a property of an object anywhere:

```
let obj = { ['prop']: 42 }
console.log(obj.prop) 
console.log(obj['prop'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object[attribute]` syntax to refer to a property of an object.

```js
// Example:

let attr = 'candy';
let obj = {};

obj['attr'] = 'cone';
console.log(obj);     // { attr: 'cane' }

obj[attr] = 'cane';
console.log(obj);     // { attr: 'cone', candy: 'cane' }
```

```js
// Your Solution:

function createData(_id) {
  var _temp = "20C";
  var _battery = "60%";
  var _data = {};

  _data[_id] = {
    temp: _temp,
    battery: _battery,
  };

  console.log(_data);
}

createData("Thermometer1"); // { Thermometer1: { temp: '20C', battery: '60%' } }
```